# Can I transfer secondary OS to ssd drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I am running dual boot centos/windows.

Is it possible with lVm to migrate the linux partitions from hdd to ssd?
If possible a summary of what needs to be done or links to guides for 'how to'?

(Not a windows question)

Comment: Every part of your post is completely [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) for serverfault.  Copy and paste your question into Google.

Comment: Also, please don't put useless, inflammatory stuff like "Death to Windows" in your posts.

Comment: You are not allowed to ask off-topic questions here. You are also not allowed to be rude to other people here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the tips from the peanut gallary.  I did google the revised question and found [How do I move my LVM  ...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161279/how-do-i-move-my-lvm-250-gb-root-partition-to-a-new-120gb-hard-disk)